# checksum in recipe didn't be checked

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have a recipe:

```
BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM = "1"

SRC_URI += "file://foo1.zip;md5sum=1234;unpack=0"
SRC_URI += "file://foo2.tar.gz;md5sum=5678;unpack=0"
```

Both checksums are wrong, but they can still pass bitbake.

Comment: I don't think local URIs are checksummed: if someone can modify local files they can almost certainly modify the recipe (or the checksum code) as well.

Comment: Indeed in this [section](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#the-download-fetch), It says `For non-local archive downloads, the fetcher code can verify SHA-256 and MD5 checksums...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do file check by hand with something like:

```
ZOO1_MD5 = "1234"

python do_package_prepend(){ 
    input = oe.path.join(d.getVar('B'), 'foo1.zip')
    cks = bb.utils.md5_file(input)
    xpct = d.getVar('ZOO1_MD5')
    if cks != xpct:
        raise bb.fetch2.FetchError("MD5 fails for ...")
}
```

Another solution could be to put zoo1.zip in separate git repository and rely on git fetcher checks.